# Add Jquery to simple PHP calendar

Tags: php, jquery, calendar

The idea is to load the calendar without refreshing the page. What am i doing wrong? it showing a blank page

External file: Calendar.php

```
<?php
$year = (isset($_POST['year'])) ? $_POST['year'] : date("Y");
$week = (isset($_POST['week'])) ? $_POST['week'] : date('W');
  if($week > 52) {
    $year++;
    $week = 1;
  } elseif($week < 1) {
    $year--;
    $week = 52;
  }
 ?>

<table id="calenderWeek" border="1px">
<tr>
<?php
    $week = $_GET['week'];
    if($week < 10) {
        $week = '0'. $week;
    }
    for($day= 1; $day <= 7; $day++) {
        $d = strtotime($year ."W". $week . $day);
        echo "<td>". date('l', $d) ."<br>". date('d M', $d) ."</td>";
    }
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>load demo</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="target">

</div>

<script>
 function load(week, year) {
 $("#target").load( "calender.php #calenderWeek", {"week":week, "year":year}         );}
</script>
```

The idea is to load the calendar without refreshing the page. What am i doing wrong? it showing a blank page

Comment: Google more about AJAX for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is not really an answer, but i think you Need to understand this:

Your PHP only generates the HTML for one week. So if you want to Change the week with JS you will have to generate the HTML for the new Weeks in JS. Then you can just do all the work in JS.

Another way would be to generate more than one weeks with php, and only Display one of them.
Then you could hide and Show another week with JS.
This would be useful if you can only go back and forth a certain amount of weeks.

If you need to select a week without restrictions, you will have to do the calender in pure JS or reload at least the calender part of the page.

Do reload only the calnder part, you have to make a new site with only the calender Generation in it:

calender.php

```
<?php
$year = (isset($_POST['year'])) ? $_POST['year'] : date("Y");
$week = (isset($_POST['week'])) ? $_POST['week'] : date('W');
if($week > 52) {
    $year++;
    $week = 1;
} elseif($week < 1) {
    $year--;
    $week = 52;
}
?>
<table id="calenderWeek" border="1px">
<tr>
    <?php
        $week = $_GET['week'];
        if($week < 10) {
            $week = '0'. $week;
        }
        for($day= 1; $day <= 7; $day++) {
            $d = strtotime($year ."W". $week . $day);
            echo "<td>". date('l', $d) ."<br>". date('d M', $d) ."</td>";
        }
    ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then just load it into the div on the page where you want it:

```
<script>
 function loadWeek(week, year)
 $( "#target" ).load( "/calender.php #calenderWeek", {"week":week, "year":year} );

/* Here call the function on page loading...*/
$( document ).ready( loadWeek(2,2016));

</script>
```

that load function you can call on document.ready and on the click on the button, and will just take the Content from #calenderWeek and put it inside the #target div

```
<div id="target">

</div>
```

For more Information take a look at the load function:
http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: Is it possible to manipulate it using a <div> </div> so that the div just refresh instead of the whole page @DoktorOSwaldo

Comment: yes of course, but for me it is reloading, but thank you anyway, I will update the answer.

Comment: @Leednetz please provide your specific code, what you have tried and where you got Errors.

Comment: I edited my initial question to the specific code i tried. it not showing any error.. It just shows a blank page @Doktor OSwaldo

Comment: @Leednetz of course it is showing a blank, because you defined a function but never called it. I have inserted a .ready function into the js to call the function with for now static numbers.